# Is it possible to show Django-CMS menus in a non-CMS application?

Tags: django, django-cms

In Django project I have Django-CMS and another application (let's call it "App B"). I want a consistent set of menus across both apps. I have added the new items with `menu_pool.register_menu`. [This page](http://docs.django-cms.org/en/2.1.0/getting_started/navigation.html) says

> Please note that menus were originally implemented to be application-independant and as such, live in the menus application instead of the “normal” cms

so I would expect that I can write the same menu tag in the template for "App B" as for CMS. I have this in both my "App B" template and my CMS template:

```
<ul>{% show_menu 0 100 0 1  %}</ul>
```

In the CMS it works, showing the full menu. In "App B" it just renders blank:

```
<ul></ul>
```

I don't want to have to create a plugin or app hook unless I have to. Do I have to?

EDIT: I have tried this with an App-Hook and it still doesn't work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a template tag for that: [show_menu_below_id](http://docs.django-cms.org/en/2.1.0/getting_started/navigation.html#show-menu-below-id)

Answer (score 1):

To further quote:

> Note
>
> All views that are attached like this must return a RequestContext instance instead of the default Context instance.

I just had to add `context_instance=RequestContext(request)` to my `render_to_response`s.